# Microsoft virtual wifi mini adapter does not work after recovering from hibernate

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, hibernate

I use the virtual wlan as an virtual access point and start and stop it via commandline. It works fine. The power management on this device is off and I stop the hosted network before I hibernate. But after recovering from hibernation it disappears from the list of network adapter and cannot be started from the command line. Also it reappears and works normal if I restart my system. I dont know of any other third party service I use that interfere with it. Please help .

Answer (score 0):

Try to update wireless adapter and Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport adapter "find them in Device manager"

I had the same problem on my Toshiba C660 - windows 7 64bit and it solved like that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, updating the driver didn't work for me. But I was able to regain access to the hosted network by **disabling** and **reenabling** the wifi and ethernet adapters, so I could avoid restarting which was a real pain.

Seriously, it was as simple as 1) disabling the wifi connection, 2) disabling the ethernet connection, 3) reenable the ethernet connection, 4) reenable the wifi connection. As soon as I did it, the 2nd wifi connection (Microsoft Virtual) immediately reappeared, and I could reenable Internet sharing.